# Check if todays is first weekday of month?

Tags: vb.net

I wish to check if the current date is the first weekday of the month, I wondered if there is an easier way to do this?  Currently, I use the following coding to determine the first weekday and then match it to another textbox which has todays date.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Dte As Date = FirstMonday(1, 2015)
        Me.TextBox1.Text = Dte.ToString
    End Sub

   Private Function FirstMonday(ByVal Mnth As Integer, ByVal year As Integer) As Date

        Dim Dte As Date = New Date(year, Mnth, 1)

        Do While Dte.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Monday
            Dte = Dte.AddDays(1)
        Loop
        Return Dte

    End Function
```

Comment: nope thats perfectly reasonable. you could always do the math to find the current day of week and just add that.

Comment: Ok, I have two additional questions. I can only get it to work by entering the month and year manually Dim Dte As Date = FirstMonday(1, 2015) how would i get it to have the current month and year? I have tried   Dim Dte As Date = FirstMonday(mm, yyyy) but it errors? also finally the code shows the format as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss so how would i remove the hh:mm:ss part and only ahve teh date? ie show 05/01/2015 00:00:00 as 05/01/2015.

Comment: Use `DateTime.Today`'s `Year` and `Month` properties.

Comment: Are you interested in the first weekday or the first Monday? For example, do you want Thursday Jan 1st or Monday Jan 5th? Because your question title says something different from what your code does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this function

```
Public Function FirstMonday(year As Integer, month As Integer) As DateTime
    Dim firstDay As New DateTime(year, month, 1)
    If firstDay.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday Then
        Return firstDay
    Else
        Dim days = DayOfWeek.Monday - firstDay.DayOfWeek ' in case the first day was less than monday
        If firstDay.DayOfWeek > DayOfWeek.Monday Then days = 7 - firstDay.DayOfWeek + DayOfWeek.Monday ' in case if the first day was > monday              
        Return firstDay.AddDays(days)
    End If
End Function
```

to use this function

```
dim monday=FirstMonday(2014,6) ' for example
```

in case you want to generalize the function to work with any DayOfWeek, you can use the following function

```
Public Function FirstDayOfWeek(year As Integer, month As Integer, Day As DayOfWeek) As DateTime
    Dim firstDay As New DateTime(year, month, 1)
    If firstDay.DayOfWeek = Day Then
        Return firstDay
    Else
        Dim days = Day - firstDay.DayOfWeek ' in case the first day was less than DayOfWeek
        If firstDay.DayOfWeek > Day Then days = 7 - firstDay.DayOfWeek + Day ' in case if the first day was > DayOfWeek             
        Return firstDay.AddDays(days)
    End If
End Function
```

here a working [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rxVM93)

Result for the demo is: **Which is accurate**

```
First Monday in [Jan 2014] is 06 Jan 2014
First Monday in [Feb 2014] is 03 Feb 2014
First Monday in [Mar 2014] is 03 Mar 2014
First Monday in [Apr 2014] is 07 Apr 2014
First Monday in [May 2014] is 05 May 2014
First Monday in [Jun 2014] is 02 Jun 2014
First Monday in [Jul 2014] is 07 Jul 2014
First Monday in [Aug 2014] is 04 Aug 2014
First Monday in [Sep 2014] is 01 Sep 2014
First Monday in [Oct 2014] is 06 Oct 2014
First Monday in [Nov 2014] is 03 Nov 2014
First Monday in [Dec 2014] is 01 Dec 2014
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a function that returns the first Monday of the month, another one that validates if the given date is this Monday, and finally a function that does this validation but with today.

```
private static DateTime FirstMonday(int month, int year)
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    int daysToAdd = 8 - (int)date.DayOfWeek;
    if (daysToAdd >= 7)
        daysToAdd -= 7;
    return date.AddDays(daysToAdd);
}

private static bool IsFirstMondayOfMonth(DateTime date)
{
    if (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday || date.Day > 7)
        return false;
    return true;
}

private static bool IsTodayFirstMondayOfMonth()
{
    if (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday || DateTime.Today.Day > 7)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

They are in C# but I'm sure you can easily convert them to VB.

Finally, about your request in the comment, you can simply use `date.ToShortDateString()` to get the dd/MM/yyyy format, if that's your configured culture. If you want to make sure you use that format under all circumstances, use `date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` instead.

Comment: `date.ToShortDateString()` uses dd/MM/yyyy format on my computer... you might want to revise that part of your answer ;)

Comment: I assumed he uses the invariant culture (US format), but actually yes, any `ToString` method will use the current culture for the format unless an `IFormatProvider` is provided.

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to check if the current date is the first weekday of the month

Great, but what does the first Monday have to do with that? What if the month starts on a Friday? Or a Tuesday? Then the first Monday is the wrong result.

I find the easiest way to do this is to start at the beginning of the month and just count forward until you find a week day:

```
Private Shared Function FirstWeekDayOfCurrentMonth() As DateTime
    'we check DateTime.Today twice in this function
    'so save first result to avoid race condition near midnight
    Dim current As DateTime = Date.Today 

    current = current.AddDays(-1 * (current.Day - 1) )      
    While current.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday OrElse current.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday
       current = current.AddDays(1)
    End While

    Return current 
End Function
```

I know it sometimes feels inefficient to need to write a loop for something like this, but at most you'll have two iterations with this code, so it's really still pretty good. Then the check becomes trivial:

```
Private Shared Function IsFirstWeekDayOfCurrentMonth() As Boolean
     Return DateTime.Today.Equals( FirstWeekDayOfCurrentMonth() )
End Function
```

Note that in the first function, I saved a copy of the `DateTime.Today` value, to avoid the possibility of weird results if this runs as midnight on the system clock turns over. Really, you should do this across functions as well, and so a better program design would work like this:

```
Private Shared Function FirstWeekDayOfMonth(DateTime month) As DateTime
    'remove any time component and set to first day of the month
    month = month.Date.AddDays(-1 * (current.Day - 1) ) 

    While month.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday OrElse month.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday
       month = month.AddDays(1)
    End While

    Return month
End Function

Private Shared Function IsFirstWeekDayOfMonth(DateTime dateToCheck ) As Boolean
     Return dateToCheck.Date.Equals( FirstWeekDayOfMonth(dateToCheck) )
End Function
```

And then you'd call it like this:

```
If IsFirstWeekDayOfMonth(DateTime.Today) Then
    '...
End IF
```